# align data by word into column

Tags: shell, sed, command-line, text-formatting, columns

How can I align data into pretty columns relative to given word?

For example, I have output of the `route -n` command:

```
default via 172.20.99.254 dev eth0 
87.33.17.71 dev tun0 scope link 
89.223.15.12 via 172.20.99.254 dev eth0 src 172.20.99.74 
172.20.9.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.99.74 
65.46.5.89 dev tun0 scope link 
192.168.11.0/24 dev tun0 scope link 
45.211.111.7 dev tun0 scope link
```

and I would like to align it by the word `dev`, so that the column containing the word `dev` is aligned:

```
default via 172.20.99.254       dev eth0 
87.33.17.71                     dev tun0 scope link 
89.223.15.12 via 172.20.99.254  dev eth0 src 172.20.99.74 
172.20.9.0/24                   dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.99.74 
65.46.5.89                      dev tun0 scope link 
192.168.11.0/24                 dev tun0 scope link 
45.211.111.7                    dev tun0 scope link
```

I cannot just naively replace fist space character with a tab, because sometimes I need 1 tab, other times I need 3 tabs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use a character that I am sure it doesn't exist into file, as a dummy separator for the `column` command, like:

```
$ sed 's/dev/@dev/' file | column -ts@
default via 172.20.99.254        dev eth0 
87.33.17.71                      dev tun0 scope link 
89.223.15.12 via 172.20.99.254   dev eth0 src 172.20.99.74 
172.20.9.0/24                    dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.99.74 
65.46.5.89                       dev tun0 scope link 
192.168.11.0/24                  dev tun0 scope link 
45.211.111.7                     dev tun0 scope link
```

You can also use `-o` (specify the output separator) together with `column`, you can try with `-o ""` or `-o " "` to see behaviour.

Also the above `sed` substitutes only the first occurence, and a simple matching was used, maybe you 'd need a more strict matching for other cases, like matching surrounding whitespaces.

Comment: that is quite clever!